# Variation of Bin-Packing problem with class constraints

Tags: algorithm, optimization, bin-packing

I am working with the following variation of the Bin Packing optimization problem:

We have n items with different weights that can be classified into two classes (X and Y). Each item needs to be assigned to a bin where all bins have the same fixed capacity. As with the classic Bin Packing problem, the goal is to minimize the number of bins. However, I furthermore want to minimize the number of bins containing both classes X and Y.

I have been doing some research but have not yet found an algorithm to find the optimal solution to this problem.

I tried searching for variations of the class-constrained bin packing problem but have only found the maximum number of classes to be a constraint instead of minimizing the number of bins containing items of both classes.

Comment: Try an integer-programming approach. There are lots of different approaches modelling it and some of those will scale worse (bin-duplication), some of those will scale better with `n` (*big-M* formulations).

Comment: You need to define the relation of number of bins and number of bins containing both classes, e.g. is the class constraint just secondary or do you minimize number of bins + number of bins containing both classes (sum of the two)?